# Android: 2.1 App Layout Compatibility with Honeycomb 3.2

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

So I'm trying to make my Android 2.1 (Eclair) app be compatible in terms of layout on a higher resolution, 10.1 inch 3.2 Honeycomb tablet.

I've read these pages: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
And: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts

The new size quantifiers make it more dynamic for app's to dynamically change their layout according to their dpi... but 2.1 doesn't support that obviously.

**So.. am I stuck using res/layout-xlarge to support most tablets?**

The reason I want it compatible for both 2.1 and 3.2 is so that one app is universal for all handsets and tablets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any reason why you can't build your app with the 3.2 sdk?  It's backwards compatible and runs just fine on 2.1. Then you should be able to use the new size quantifiers just fine.

Comment: WHAT!?  WOW.  I just thought using the 3.2 SDK might make it incompatible with a 2.1 app because of new API's and whatnot.  Wow.. I guess problem solved then if this is true.

Comment: Tried it out.. the device chooser on Eclipse shows an X next to the target but who cares!  It works!  Thanks Rymnel!